# Next.js on vercel server has different process.env.PWD for static routes and dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, vercel, app-router

I'm using the app router and deploying on vercel.
I have a directory in the root of my project with the name `blog` where I put markdown files.
locally I reach for them by doing: `./blog/a-blog-post.md` which work whether the route is dynamic or static but this only worked for static routes on the server. I tried to see what is the process.env.PWD in both and got:
static: `/vercel/path0/`
dynamic: `/var/task/`

I tried appending the routes with `process.cwd()` or an absolute path like `/blog/a-blog-post.md` but with the same results

how can I reach the filesystem on the server in a consistent way whatever the route I am in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know vercel deploys your code not to a single server but to multiple (on the edge). so using the filesystem is not a good idea.

You may figure out if you are on the Edge using this:

```
if (typeof EdgeRuntime !== 'string') {
  // dead-code elimination is enabled for the code inside this block
}
```

[https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions/edge-runtime#check-if-you're-running-on-the-edge-runtime](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions/edge-runtime#check-if-you%27re-running-on-the-edge-runtime)

There is this depricated Filesystem API: https://vercel.com/docs/file-system-api/v2 and a Buildoutput API: https://vercel.com/docs/build-output-api/v3
But overall it is not advised to use the FS in such cases.

If you need to write files somethere, maybe use a service like minio / AWS, or a Database.
If you want to communicate over the filesystem, try to use something like Kafka or MQTT.